# Extract inversed duplicated values sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

- `Likes` (IDPerfilA, IDPerfilB, Data)
- `Amizade` (IDPerfilA, IDPerfilB, Data)

*Amizade = Friends in English.

My table likes is uploaded with many likes, with the constraint that does not allow that IDPerfilA likes the same IDperfilB (EX: user with the ID 4 con not like user with the ID 4).

Now, I want to upload my friends table with the following ID's:

If, exists in the likes table user 4 likes 8 and 8 likes 4, then it is an friendship, so they go to friends and are deleted from likes.

I've tried the following, but my table friends as inversed duplicated values (Ex: 4 is friends with 8 and 8 is friends with 4)

```
INSERT INTO AMIZADE (IDPERFILA,
                     IDPERFILB,
                     DATA)
SELECT a.IDPERFILA, a.IDPERFILB, a.DATA
FROM LIKES as a, LIKES as b
WHERE (a.IDPERFILB = b.IDPERFILA AND a.IDPERFILA = b.IDPERFILB)
```

I used the following code to delete friends from likes:

```
DELETE LIKES
from 
LIKES as l inner join amizade as a
on a.IDPERFILA = l.IDPERFILA
    and a.IDPERFILB = l.IDPERFILB
    and a.DATA = l.DATA
```

If someone could help me it would be great! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

will this work?

```
INSERT INTO AMIZADE (IDPERFILA,
                     IDPERFILB,
                     DATA)
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN (a.IDPERFILA > a.IDPERFILB) THEN a.IDPERFILA
            ELSE a.IDPERFILB
            END
        , CASE WHEN (a.IDPERFILA <= a.IDPERFILB) THEN a.IDPERFILB
            ELSE a.IDPERFILA
            END
        , a.DATA
FROM LIKES as a, LIKES as b
WHERE (a.IDPERFILB = b.IDPERFILA AND a.IDPERFILA = b.IDPERFILB)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want the pair (4, 8) to appear in the friends table only once.  I would go for:

```
INSERT INTO AMIZADE (IDPERFILA, IDPERFILB, DATA)
    SELECT l.IDPERFILA, l.IDPERFILB, l.DATA
    FROM LIKES l
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM LIKES l2
                  WHERE l2.IDPERFILA = l.IDPERFILB AND l2.IDPERFILB = l.IDPERFILA
                 ) AND
          l.IDPERFILA < l2.IDPERFILB;
```

You can remove the last condition if you want both pairs in the `amizade` table.

You might also want to enforce that a given pair only goes into the `amizade` table once.  If so, you can do this with a unique index and a check constraint:

```
alter table amizade constraint chk_amizade_idperfilA_idperfilB
    check (idperfilA < idperfilB);

alter table amizade constraint unq_amizade_idperfilA_idperfilB
    unique (idperfilA, idperilB);
```

These two checks will ensure that the friendship pairs are unique.  Note:  you do need to be careful about how you insert the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO AMIZADE (IDPERFILA,
                 IDPERFILB,
                 DATA)
SELECT a.IDPERFILA, a.IDPERFILB, a.DATA
FROM LIKES as a, LIKES as b
WHERE (a.IDPERFILB = b.IDPERFILA AND a.IDPERFILA = b.IDPERFILB)
**and (a.IDPrfila > a.IDPerfilb)**
```

just add the statement inbetween de ** and worked. Thank you for the tips